# Javascript - pause execution until flag becomes true

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization, wait

how can i pause a javascript execution until a flag becomes true?

For Example, i've a xml message like this:

```
[...]
<action>
    <resource update>id</resourceupdate>
</action>
<action>
    <event>id1</event>
</action>
<action>
    <event>id2</event>
</action>
<action>
    <event>id3</event>
</action>
[...]
```

I wish that the event nodes are processed only after processing node resourceupdate (which requires more time to be served, as it requires the loading of a page):

in javascript to process this message with an iterator (each) i've tried:

```
$(_response).find('ACTION').each(function() {       
if (tagName=="RESOURCEUPDATE") {
    ready = false;
    //load the resource with selected id in an iframe
} else if (tagName=="EVENT") {
    browserLoaded();   //the waiting function
    eventhandler();  //consume the event
}
});
```

the waiting function is:

```
function browserLoaded() {
if (!ready) {
    setTimeout(browserLoaded(),1000);
}
}
```

and the ready var becomes true when the iframe is loaded:

```
$(iframe).load(function() {
    ready = true;
});
```

but when execute i'll catch this error:

```
 Maximum call stack size exceeded error
```

any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout(browserLoaded(),1000);` executes your function. You just want to reference your function; remove the `()` so that it's `setTimeout(browserLoaded, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Ok, no more error, but execution doesn't stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a bad idea to use some kind of a flag. You have to use Deferred Pattern. Something like this:

```
var resources = [];
$(_response).find('ACTION').each(function() {
  var deferred = resources.length > 0 ? resources[resources.length - 1] : null;

  switch (tagName) {
    case "RESOURCEUPDATE":
      deferred = $.Deferred();

      //load the resource with selected id in an iframe
      $(iframe).bind('load', function () {
        deferred.resolve(/*specific arg1, arg2, arg3, ...*/)
      });
      resources.push(deferred);
      break;
    case "EVENT":       
      if (deferred) {
         deferred.done(function (/*specific arg1, arg2, arg3, ...*/) {
            // process event node
         });
      }
      break;
  }
});

// clean up deferreds objects when all them will be processed
$.when.apply($, resources).then(function() {
  resources.length = 0;
})
```

**P.S.**: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: interesting, I'll give a look

Comment: This is the right answer; the code is not exactly what I needed but the advice on deferred allowed me to find the best solution for my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this function which call itself until the stack is full:

```
function browserLoaded() {
  if (!ready) {
    //here you call browserLoaded function instead of passing a reference to the function
    setTimeout(browserLoaded() ,1000);
  }
}
```

Your function should look like this:

```
function browserLoaded() {
  if (!ready) {
    // note the missing "()"
    setTimeout(browserLoaded, 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible design. You don't need the 'waiting' timeout mechanism. If you are loading the pages via jQuery ajax request, make use of the callback functions to continue with your code execution (you can perhaps keep track of the 'current' item being processed and continue with the next). If you are loading iFrames, that's bad design too, you should move to the jQuery ajax way.

Comment: I greatly simplified the code to not include unnecessary information.

In reality, the load function of the iframe contains several handlers that intercept user interaction send xml messages to a servlet.
This stores them and sends them to other clients more or less expressed in the syntax of the Get on through asynchronous callback function which is (simplified) that expressed above.

I can not process messages in the callback of the iframe load because these, being asynchronous, not necessarily arrive to load the iframe

Comment: hmm, can't you make use of the onLoad event of the iFrame at least?

Comment: not to process messages, but at most to trigger a variable (ready) :(

Comment: If you can trigger a variable (in the parent of the iFrame) you should be able to also invoke a function. Like: [iframe onLoad='parent.continueWithNextOne();'] isn't that possible? If the iframe and the parent are within the same domain, that should be possible?

Comment: is not sure that the messages arrive in this sequence, it could get even just <action> <event/> </ action>. and i think is a bad design write two code brach identically. The case explained above is a particular case, i would not overturn the code for a particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

One quick hack that you could do is just set up a polling loop: use setInterval to check every once in a while if the variable has been set and clearInterval and continue execution when its time.

Any way, its going to be a pain to do things. Essentially, the only way to tell something in Javascript to run latter is to package it inside a function. After you do this it gets easier though, since you can pass that function around and have the async code call it back when you are done.

For example, your processing might look something like this:

```
//this is a simple "semaphore" pattern:
var things_to_load_count = 1
var check_if_done(){
    things_to_load_count--;
    if(things_to_load_count <= 0){
        //code to do stuff after you finish loading
    }
};

$(_response).find('ACTION').each(function() {
    if (tagName=="RESOURCEUPDATE") {
        things_to_load_count++;
        run_code_to_load_stuff( check_if_done )
        //make sure that the run_code_to_load_stuff function
        //calls the callback you passed it once its done.
    } else if (tagName=="EVENT") {
        //process one of the normal nodes
    }
});

//this will run the remaining code if we loaded everything
//but will do nothing if we are still waiting.
check_if_done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the ready variable that set true in the iframe load function is the same as the one that is checked before another settimeout is called. It seems that the one in the iframe load function is a local variable and the other one a global variable.

Or both ready variables are local.

Comment: i declare var ready = true at the beginning of my core.js (outside any branch or function); after i made only assignment and never declare the variable elsewhere.